# can odata and non odata routes co exists

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

i am using asp.net core 3.x and i have installed .net core's odata nuget.

in my services section i have setup odata like this

```
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddODataQueryFilter();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
```

and configuration looks like this.

```
 app.UseMvc(b =>
        {
            b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();

        });
```

when i use  /odata/Accounts i get odata response 
is it possible to get   /api/Accounts at the same time ?

```
 //[ODataRoutePrefix("Account")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
    public AccountsController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 2, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Account>>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(await _accountService.GetAllAccounts());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Odata may face errors using `$select` from .net core 3.x using `System.Text.Json` serializer . So that in your scenario you can use `AddNewtonsoftJson` as workaround . Note: If the `AddNewtonsoftJson` method isn't available, make sure that you installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package . Code sample below is for your reference :

Student.cs :

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

StudentsController.cs :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
    {
        return new List<Student>
        {
            CreateNewStudent("Cody Allen", 130),
            CreateNewStudent("Todd Ostermeier", 160),
            CreateNewStudent("Viral Pandya", 140)
        };
    }

    private static Student CreateNewStudent(string name, int score)
    {
        return new Student
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = name,
            Score = score
        };
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddControllers(mvcOptions =>
          mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();

services.AddOData();
services.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

Configure :

```
app.UseMvc(b =>
{
    b.Select().Filter();
    b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
    b.EnableDependencyInjection();  //add this line

});
```

GetEdmModel :

```
IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");

    return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

So that both `https://localhost:44334/odata/students?$select=name` and `https://localhost:44334/api/students?$select=name`would return data .